# How to Convert real time tick by tick data in O(N) time complexity

Tags: node.js, data-structures, websocket, time-complexity, algorithmic-trading

I have written a code that converts real-time tick by tick data into 5min, 10min 15min, and 30min intervals but the problem is the time complexity this code run in O(N * M) which is slow for converting real-time data into interval.

```
    const arbitaryMinCandles = new Map();
    ["ITC_EQ"].forEach(instrument => {
        arbitaryMinCandles.set(instrument, []); 
    });

for(const [symbol,ticks] of oneMinCandle.entries()){

    let stack = [ticks[0]];
    let high = -Infinity 
    let low = Infinity
    let open = 0;
    let close = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++){
        if(ticks[i].timestamp - stack[0].timestamp <= 300){
            high = Math.max(high, ticks[i].high);
            low = Math.min(low, ticks[i].low);
        }

        if(ticks[i].timestamp - stack[0].timestamp === 500){
            let temp = stack.pop();
            open = temp.open;
            close = ticks[i].close;
            stack.push(ticks[i + 1]);
            arbitaryMinCandles.get(symbol).push({open, high, low, close, isComplete: true})
            high = -Infinity;
            low = Infinity;
            open = 0;
            close = 0;
        }
    }

}
console.log(arbitaryMinCandles);
```

The input would be something like this

```
const oneMinCandle = new Map([
  [
    'ITC_EQ',
    [
      {
        open: 424.10,
        high: 424.60,
        low: 422.50,
        close: 422.95,
        timestamp: 1683712800 
        // 9:15
      },
      {
        // 9:16
        open: 422.95,
        high: 424.45,
        low: 422.95,
        close: 424.45,
        timestamp: 1683712860
      },
      {
        // 9:17
        open: 424.30,
        high: 425.00,
        low: 424.15,
        close: 424.40,
        timestamp: 1683712920 
      },
      {
        // 9:18
        open: 424.40,
        high: 425.00,
        low: 424.15,
        close: 424.95,
        timestamp: 1683712980 
      },
      {
        // 9:19
        open: 424.95,
        high: 425.65,
        low: 424.80,
        close: 425.25,
        timestamp: 1683713040
      },
      {
        // 9:20
        open: 425.20,
        high: 425.75,
        low: 425.10,
        close: 425.45,
        timestamp: 1683713100 
      },
        {
            // 9:21
        open: 425.60,
        high: 425.60,
        low: 424.55,
        close: 425.25,
        timestamp: 1683713160 
      },
         {
            // 9:22
        open: 425.35,
        high: 425.80,
        low: 425.20,
        close: 425.60,
        timestamp: 1683713160 
      },
         {
            // 9:23
        open: 425.60,
        high: 426.00,
        low: 425.60,
        close: 426.00,
        timestamp: 1683713280 
      },
        {
            // 9:24
        open: 425.90,
        high: 426.00,
        low: 425.70,
        close: 425.70,
        timestamp: 1683713340 
      },
       {
        // 9:25
        open: 425.70,
        high: 425.70,
        low: 425.20,
        close: 425.50,
        timestamp: 1683713400 
      },
       {
        // 9:26
        open: 425.45,
        high: 425.45,
        low: 425.00,
        close: 425.25,
        timestamp: 1683713460 
      },
       {
        // 9:27
        open: 425.20,
        high: 425.40,
        low: 425.20,
        close: 425.25,
        timestamp: 1683713520 
      },
       {
        // 9:28
        open: 425.25,
        high: 425.75,
        low: 425.20,
        close: 425.70,
        timestamp: 1683713580 
      },
       {
        // 9:29
        open: 425.70,
        high: 425.90,
        low: 425.60,
        close: 425.70,
        timestamp: 1683713640 
      },
       {
        // 9:30
        open: 425.80,
        high: 425.80,
        low: 425.50,
        close: 425.65,
        timestamp: 1683713700 
      },
       {
        // 9:31
        open: 425.60,
        high: 425.85,
        low: 425.60,
        close: 425.80,
        timestamp: 1683713760 
      },
       {
        // 9:32
        open: 425.60,
        high: 425.75,
        low: 425.25,
        close: 425.25,
        timestamp: 1683713820 
      },
       {
        // 9:33
        open: 425.10,
        high: 425.65,
        low: 425.10,
        close: 425.45,
        timestamp: 1683713880 
      },
       {
        // 9:34
        open: 425.50,
        high: 426.10,
        low: 425.50,
        close: 425.55,
        timestamp: 1683713940 
      },
       {
        // 9:35
        open: 425.75,
        high: 425.95,
        low: 425.70,
        close: 425.70,
        timestamp: 1683714000 
      },
       {
        // 9:36
        open: 425.70,
        high: 425.85,
        low: 425.20,
        close: 425.20,
        timestamp: 1683714060 
      },
    ]
  ],
]);
```

And the output for 5 min interval would be

```
Map(1) {
  'ITC_EQ' => [
    {
      open: 424.1,
      high: 425.65,
      low: 422.5,
      close: 425.25,
      isComplete: true
    },
    {
      open: 425.2,
      high: 426,
      low: 424.55,
      close: 425.7,
      isComplete: true
    },
    {
      open: 425.7,
      high: 425.9,
      low: 425,
      close: 425.7,
      isComplete: true
    },
    {
      open: 425.8,
      high: 426.1,
      low: 425.1,
      close: 425.55,
      isComplete: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Can we optimize this code to code to run at O(N) ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem.
You are receiving a bunch of small intervals, and you want to join them to a bigger interval in real time. But they aren't necessarily in order or sequential?

Comment: would it work to wait for 5 minutes, accumulate all the data points, and then send out the answer?
It seems that you need to find the lowest low and the highest high for each interval.

Comment: I'd also process this as a stream rather than putting all in a list then processing a result list..
Basically: create a new high / low, while time is less than 5 mins, update high and low, if 5 mins is up send resulting high/low, and go to first step